# Flex FileReference upload() and .data ... does this load the whole file into memory?

Tags: apache-flex, file-upload, filereference

I need to upload a very large file to my server, through my Flex application, and I see that Flex Filereference upload() seems to be able to handle it. Does the upload() methods uploads a 'stream' to the servlet, or does it sends the whole ByteArray (As I understand it, the ByteArray will have the whole file contents, so a >1Gb file will flood my memory).

I haven't found confirmation of one or the other. It seems flex.net.FileReference source code is part of flash, not the open source flex, so I cant take a peek.

Anyone can confirm or deny the usage of the whole byteArray when sending file contents to the server?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know internals, but I would assume that is how it works.  Flash needs the whole file before it can perform actions on it; it does not act as a "byteArray Streamer" from your hard drive to server.  If you're dealing w/ very large files, I strongly recommend against using HTTP to upload said files; as that is not it's intended purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to upload big files using Flash, the loading of the file into memory is not your biggest concern - the upload itself is quite unreliable. According to the [Flex reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html) Flash player officially supports upload file sizes of up to 100 MB. My experience confirms that big file uploads often fail. You may check this [file upload component](http://www.zehnet.de/2009/02/23/flex-fileupload-component/) for uploading large files in chinks and resuming partial uploads. However this solution also needs to fully load the file into memory before starting the upload.

Answer (score 0):

> The [following sample HTTP POST request](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/FileReference.html) is sent from Flash Player to a server-side script if no parameters are specified:

```
  POST /handler.cfm HTTP/1.1 
  Accept: text/*
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; 
  boundary=----------Ij5ae0ae0KM7GI3KM7 
  User-Agent: Shockwave Flash 
  Host: www.example.com 
  Content-Length: 421 
  Connection: Keep-Alive 
  Cache-Control: no-cache

  ------------Ij5GI3GI3ei4GI3ei4KM7GI3KM7KM7
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

  MyFile.jpg
  ------------Ij5GI3GI3ei4GI3ei4KM7GI3KM7KM7
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="MyFile.jpg"
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream

  FileDataHere
  ------------Ij5GI3GI3ei4GI3ei4KM7GI3KM7KM7
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

  Submit Query
  ------------Ij5GI3GI3ei4GI3ei4KM7GI3KM7KM7--
```

It looks similar to the [post request generated by a file input html control](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html). So it's not a ByteArray, but still the browser would need to load the file to its memory before sending it; 1GB is too much for any file upload - flash or not.